# How to get the localised languages of my iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I want to add a feature to change the app language inside the app (independent of the iPhone language).

To show the available languages, instead of hardcoding them I want to get the list of supported localised languages and make it dynamic. 
Then each time I add a new localised language it will be automatically added to the list of available languages.

There is any way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
let languageIds = Bundle.main.localizations
```

to get the list of language ids. Then you can convert each language id into the localized language name with:

```
let loc = Locale(identifier: langId)
let name = loc.localizedString(forLanguageCode: langId) ?? "Unknown"
```

Here's some code that builds a dictionary of available languages in your app's bundle. It is keyed on the locale id (language id) and each value is the localized language name for each locale id.

```
let langIds = Bundle.main.localizations
var languages = [String:String]()
for langId in langIds {
    let loc = Locale(identifier: langId)
    if let name = loc.localizedString(forLanguageCode: langId) {
        languages[langId] = name
    } else {
        // this should never be reached
    }
}
```

The `Bundle` class also provides the `preferredLocalizations` property and a few other related properties and functions.